# c# - How could I handle multiple bitmap formats when loaded initially into a form?

Tags: c#

A single image can be initially loaded from an application subfolder into a Windows form to appear as the BackgroundImage by specifying name and image format by file extension.
However I can't figure out a way to support different image formats with identical names and effectively handle multiple images in my subfolder which have the same name, but different image file extensions.
I want that any supported Bitmap image called map_default(*.*) will be loaded initially as BackgroundImage if there is a single image with this name in the subfolder and that one image will be picked randomly if there are multiple images in the subfolder like this:

> application1.exe
>   defaultmap(folder):
>   -map_default.png
>   -map_default.gif
>   -map_default.bmp
>   -map_default.tiff
>   -map_default.jpeg

I saw many methods to modify path expressions, but unfortunately there seems no way to define the name of an image and specify different file extensions for it in one path expression.
On the other side it seems that I must specify an extension for an image.
I need to know the right path expression and a way to check if there is only one image in the array or several images(in this case pick one item from the array).
How could I possibly solve this?

Well, I don't have an idea for the random picking, but I my problem is always that I don't know how to read the image without specifying an extension when I load it into the Form initially.
There are many working solutions with file selector and drag and drop, but I'm unsure what to do when I load the image automatically when the Form runs:

```
BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"defaultmap\map_default.png"));
```

Can I use System.IO.Directory.GetFiles path expression with any extension?

Comment: at least post few lines of code and show what you already tried.

Comment: I'd start by getting a handle to that directory and see what options you have from there before worrying about the exact path to a particular image.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                //declare path to images directory
                string path = @"C:\MyPath\images\";
                //fill an array with file names.
                string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(path);

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(images[0]))
                {
                   //set background to hex code color
                }
                else if (String.IsNullorEmpty(images[1]))
                {
                    //set background to images[0]
                }
                else
                {
                    //set background to random array value for images
                }

            }
        }
```

If you just refuse to have a dedicated directory for images you can check for each value in the array ends with .png, .jpg, .bmp, etc.

Comment: Looks good. For the second part of my question - is there a way to include a list of my Background images in this solution, which is referenced with numbered values for random selection or is there a shorter way to do the random part directly inside else{} ?

Comment: @taraz Get values in your array. Something like int result = myarray.GetLength(0);. Then generate a random number from 0 to result, then call on images [result]